# How do I dynamically create an Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate from Expression<Func<MyClass, string>>?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I trying to append where predicates and my goal is to create the same expression as:

```
Services.Where(s => s.Name == "Modules" && s.Namespace == "Namespace");
```

I have the following code:

```
Expression<Func<Service,string>> sel1 = s => s.Name;
Expression<Func<Service,string>> sel2 = s => s.Namespace;

var val1 = Expression.Constant("Modules");
var val2 = Expression.Constant("Namespace");

Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(sel1.Body, val1);
Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(sel2.Body, val2);
var andExp = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);

ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(andExp, argParam);
```

This create the following output:

```
s => ((s.Name == "Modules") AndAlso (s.Namespace == "Namespace"))
```

However, this is faulty since the parameter for **Name** and **Namespace** isn't the same. If I change one of the expression selector to:

```
Expression<Func<Service,string>> sel2 = srv => srv.Namespace;
```

The output will be:

```
s => ((s.Name == "Modules") AndAlso (srv.Namespace == "Namespace"))
```

How can I create a valid expression with use of **sel1** and **sel2**?

**UPDATE (28 feb 2011)**

I solved it by creating invoke expressions: `Expression.Invoke` so the lambda expressions sel1 and sel2 don't necessary need to be a MemberExpression:

```
Expression<Func<Service,string>> sel1 = s => s.Name;
Expression<Func<Service,string>> sel2 = srv => srv.Namespace;

var val1 = Expression.Constant("Modules");
var val2 = Expression.Constant("Namespace");

Expression<Func<Service, bool>> lambda = m => true;
var modelParameter = lambda.Parameters.First();

// sel1 predicate
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(sel1, modelParameter);
    var binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(invokedExpr, val1);
    lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Service, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(binaryExpression, lambda.Body), lambda.Parameters);
}
// sel2 predicate
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(sel2, modelParameter);
    var binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(invokedExpr, val2);
    lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Service, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(binaryExpression, lambda.Body), lambda.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered PredicateBuilder?  It is specifically designed to solve "trying to append where predicates". http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Sounds very interesting, I will look at that. Thank you Kirk!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's hard to mix compiler-generated expression trees and hand-made ones, precisely because of this sort of thing - extracting out the ParameterExpressions is tricky. So let's start from scratch:

```
ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Service), "s");
Expression nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, "Name");
Expression namespaceProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, "Namespace");

var val1 = Expression.Constant("Modules");
var val2 = Expression.Constant("Namespace");

Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(nameProperty, val1);
Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(namespaceProperty, val2);
var andExp = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Service, bool>>(andExp, argParam);
```

One important aspect I've changed is the type passed to `Expression.Parameter` - it certainly *looks* like it should be a `Service` rather than a `string`.

I've given that a try, and it seemed to work when I called `lambda.Compile` and executed it on a couple of sample `Service` objects...

Comment: Thank you Jon! Got it to work now. Would it be totally wrong to get the member name of sel1 with: ((MemberExpression)sel1.Body).Member.Name; etc?

Comment: @Torbjörn: Um, it depends. I can't really tell what you're trying to do. It would obviously only work if `sel1`'s body really *was* a `MemberExpression`... and it might not be a property...

Comment: It sounds redundant passing `argParam` inside `Expression.Property(argParam, "Name")` and `Expression.Lambda<Func<Service, bool>>(andExp, argParam);`. I think you only had to pass to both `Expression.Property()` (for the two properties), but why should we need to pass it again to the `Expression.Lambda()`? It worked anyway for my scenario, I was just curious ;)

Comment: @Alisson: Consider what the lambda expression would look like: `s => s.Name`. See how `s` occurs in both places there? It's the same when constructing it - basically, by passing it in both places, we're trying the two uses together.

Comment: @JonSkeet now that you said, it really makes sense. What if it was a lambda like `((a,b) => a.Name == b.Name)`? Then it wouldn't make sense using the same `argParam`. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an Expression tree for nullable types, suppose you have a nullable field BoardId, you can create expression tree dynamically like this

> var nameValue="BoardId=111";

you need to determine  first Property type, whether its Nullable or not

Below code create a Dynamic tree expression for nullable and Non Nullable types

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildWhereExpression<T>(string nameValueQuery ) where  T : class 
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null;
            PropertyInfo prop = null;
            var fieldName = nameValueQuery.Split("=")[0];
            var fieldValue = nameValueQuery.Split("=")[1];
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Name.ToLower() == fieldName.ToLower())
                {
                    prop = property;
                }
            } 
            if (prop != null)
            {
                var isNullable = prop.PropertyType.IsNullableType();
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                var member = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldName); 

                if (isNullable)
                {
                    var filter1 =
                        Expression.Constant(
                            Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, member.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
                    Expression typeFilter = Expression.Convert(filter1, member.Type);
                    var body = Expression.Equal(member, typeFilter);  
                    predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);  
                }
                else
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) && likeOerator.ToLower() == "like")
                    {
                        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
                        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, prop);
                        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                        var someValue = Expression.Constant(fieldValue, typeof(string));
                        var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);
                        predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, prop.PropertyType));
                        var body = Expression.Equal(member, constant);  
                        predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter); `enter code here`
                    }
                }
            }
            return predicate;
        }
```

1- This Solution first checks for the Nullable value and generate the expression.
This is How you can determine if the type is Nullable. I have created an extension method for that purpose

```
  public static bool IsNullableType(this Type type) {  return
    type.IsGenericType &&
    (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))); }
```

2- the second step is to check the type if its string then create an expression for a string.

3- the Third step is to check is value is not nullable not string then create an expression using equal