# How to solve the error cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly?

Tags: c#, linq

```
static Func<T, object> CreateSelector<T>(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(T);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "e");
    var properties = propertyNames.Select(name => Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name)).ToArray();
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Tuple), "Create", properties.Select(p => p.Type).ToArray(), properties),
        parameter);
    return selector.Compile();
}
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    var keySelector = CreateSelector<T>(propertyNames);
    return left.Join(right, keySelector, keySelector, Tuple.Create);
}
public static bool CompareLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> lstProduct1, IEnumerable<T2> lstProduct2, List<DuplicateExpression> DuplicateExpression)
{
    string[] Fields = DuplicateExpression.Select(x => x.ExpressionName).ToArray();
    var JoinExp = lstProduct1.Join(lstProduct2, Fields);
    bool IsSuccess = true;// CompareTwoLists(lstProduct1, lstProduct2, (listProductx1, listProductx2) => JoinExp.Any());

    return IsSuccess;
}
```

When I compile the above code; I am getting error on below line

```
var JoinExp = lstProduct1.Join(lstProduct2, Fields);
```

Error is

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'AP.Classes.ListComparison.Join(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   D:\Workshop\Ap\Classes\DuplicateValidator.cs

How to solve this error? I am creating a List comparison tool.

Comment: Well look at your `Join` method - it expects *one* type argument. It expects your two sequences to be of the same type. Your `CompareLists` method allows the two sequences to be of *different* types. Which are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `bool IsSuccess =CompareTwoLists(lstProduct1, lstProduct2, (listProductx1, listProductx2) => JoinExp.Any());` I am passing these two `lists` to another function with that join. Both lists having same property.

Comment: You've missed my point. In your `CompareLists` methods, `lstProduct1` and `lstProduct2` can be of different types - for example, you could call `CompareLists(new List<string>(), new List<int>(), null);`. But in `CompareLists` you're calling `Join`, which expects two sequences of the *same* element type... both parameters are `IEnumerable<T>`. Now, do you want to be able to join sequences with different element types? If so, change `Join`. If not, change `CompareLists`.

Comment: I'm the author of the custom `Join` method (as answer to your previous question), and I should say that the assumption was that you are joining two lists of the same type. If they are different, the method should have different signature and implementation. Since you posted several questions on the same subject, it would be nice if you provide sample of what exactly are you trying to achieve, rather than implementation attempts.

Comment: Are you seeking for a method like `public static bool CompareTwoLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, Enumerable<string> propertyNames)` which returns `true` if there is any difference based on the specified properties?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Exactly that is my requirement. And also wanted to check if `propertyNames` are included in the list. If not included then return a message. i will return like json array instead of bool

Answer (score 1):

The provided custom `Join` method is not applicable, because it expects one generic type argument while your method has two.

You can use the provided `CreateSelector` implementation to implement custom `Join` / `GroupJoin` extension methods similar to the corresponding system provided methods in `Enumerable` class like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return outer.Join(inner, CreateSelector<TOuter>(propertyNames), CreateSelector<TInner>(propertyNames), resultSelector);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return outer.GroupJoin(inner, CreateSelector<TOuter>(propertyNames), CreateSelector<TInner>(propertyNames), resultSelector);
}
```

Then you can use the above custom `GroupJoin` to efficiently implement your method:

```
public static bool CompareLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, List<DuplicateExpression> DuplicateExpression)
{
    var fields = DuplicateExpression.Select(x => x.ExpressionName).ToArray();
    return list1.GroupJoin(list2, fields, (x, match) => match).All(match => match.Any())
        && list2.GroupJoin(list1, fields, (x, match) => match).All(match => match.Any());
}
```

Comment: `var fields = DuplicateExpression.Select(x => x.ExpressionName).ToArray();
                return list1.GroupJoin(list2, fields, (x, match) => match).All(match => match.Any())
                    && list2.GroupJoin(list1, fields, (x, match) => match).All(match => match.Any());` This is not getting proper result

Comment: If any one of the item duplicates in other list; it returns false. If all the items repeats then it return true

Comment: `Product p1 = new Product { ProductCode = "1", ProductName = "ABC", ProductType = "Doe", Amount = "500" };
            Product p2 = new Product { ProductCode = "2", ProductName = "DEF", ProductType = "Doe", Amount = "500" };
            Product p3 = new Product { ProductCode = "3", ProductName = "GHI", ProductType = "Doe", Amount = "500" };`

Comment: Product q1 = new Product { ProductCode = "1", ProductName = "ABC", ProductType = "Doe", Amount = "5001" };
            Product q2 = new Product { ProductCode = "21", ProductName = "DEF1", ProductType = "Doe1", Amount = "5001" };
            Product q3 = new Product { ProductCode = "31", ProductName = "GHI1", ProductType = "Doe1", Amount = "5001" };

Comment: above P1 and Q1 duplicate items. Expression fields are ProductCode,ProductName,ProductType

Comment: Well, may be you are looking for a different logic. The above returns `true` if there are **no** duplicates (i.e. if the lists are equal). If you want the opposite, just negate the result. i.e. `return !(...)`

Comment: All the rows are equal in both list then it return true. If one of the row is equal in both list then it returns false. Actually One row equals in both list means; there is one duplicate items in list. so it should return true rt?

Comment: I can't say what it **should** return - it's up to you. I gave you a mechanism to do dynamic joins, you can use it to apply the required logic. Look at my LINQ query as an example and make your own.