# I can dynamically create an Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate ,but how do i create Expression<Func<T1,T2,bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094489/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate-from-ex) i can dynamically create an Expression < Func< T, bool>> predicate

> this code can dynamically create  s=>s.Id == 1

```
ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "s");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Id");
var constExp = Expression.Constant(1);

var body = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, constExp);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(body, parameterExp);
```

but how do i create Expression < Func< T1,T2,bool>>
and
Expression < Func < T1,T2,T3,bool>>

> how dynamically create like this: (a,b)=> a.Id== 1 && b.Name == "name"

Comment: What this expression should do? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55084573/edit) your question and add an example (with static lambdas or pseudocode)

Comment: dynamically create like this: (a,b)=> a.Id== 1 && b.Name == "name"

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `Func<T, bool>` and `Func<T1, T2, bool>` is that second accept two arguments, so you need to create two parameters with `Expression.Parameter`.

Code below will create an expression

> (t1, t2) => t1.Id == 1 && t2.Name == name;

```
private static Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> CreateExpression<T1, T2>()
{
    var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
    var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");

    var idProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(t1, "Id");
    var nameProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(t2, "Name");

    var body = Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(idProp, Expression.Constant(1)),
        Expression.Equal(nameProp, Expression.Constant("name"))
    );

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, bool>>(body, t1, t2);
    return lambda;
}
```