# Convert a filter expression based on property name and value to Linq Where clause Func<T, bool>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, func

I would like to create a method that will filter my data based on a property name and value a user passes to my method. Unfortunately I cannot change the interface the code uses and I am merely extending it by creating a new type of data class. Please see code what I mean:

```
public interface IService{
     Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCollection<T>(string name, string fieldPath, string value)
}
public class MockService : IService
{
        MockDb _db = new Mock();
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCollection<T>(string fieldPath, string value)
        {
            Func<T, bool> func = <WHAT CODE IS REQUIRED HERE BASED ON THE FIELD PATH AND VALUE?>;
            return _db.GetTable<T>(func);
        }
}
```

DATA CLASS:

```
public class MockDb{
       public List<T> GetTable<T>(Func<T, bool> func){
            return somecollection.Where(func).ToList();
       }
}
```

How can I convert the input to filter, i.e. fieldPath and value into a Func?

Comment: It seems that you are using Entity Framework, and in which case, you should be using `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which can be converted to SQL. Expressions can be built dynamically; an example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094489/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate-from-ex

Comment: Not in this case, but I have used Expression<Func<T, bool>> before. This is just a Mock Db of static objects. However thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it assuming that fieldPath is the name of property and the value is a string type:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCollection<T>(string fieldPath, string value)
 {
        return _db.GetTable<T>(t=> ((string) t.GetType().GetProperty(fieldPath).GetValue(t)) == value);
 }
```

For, more generic and complex solution you should use Expression as suggested by Jonathan Barclay.

Comment: The cast to `string` is unnecessary; you can just use `Equals`: `t => t.GetType().GetProperty(fieldPath).GetValue(t).Equals(value)`.