# From string's value to expression

Tags: c#

Could anyone help me with c#, please!

If I have:

```
bool x = true; 
bool y = true;
string temp = "x & y" ;
bool myBo = temp; // my intention is myBo = x & y;  = true from the string
```

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use and build Expressions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094489/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate-from-ex

Comment: I am not sure it is a similar problem.