# How to combine multiple Func<T,Tresult> dynamically in a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, func

I have a function that returns `Func<T,TResult>`. I want to return multiple funcs in a single func with `||` of one another.

Below func is just sample but my actual code contains multiple lines of code snippet in func. In which I have to check for each value of comma separated string. Like below function there are multiple functions which returns Func<string, bool>. And all these func will combine as && for further use

```
public static Func<string, bool> GetData(string request)
{
    var data = request.Split(',');
    //This func is just sample but my actual code contains multiple lines of code snippet in func. In which I have to use each value of comma separated string.
    Func<string, bool> selector = str => str.ToUpper() == data[0] || str => str.ToLower() == data[0] ;
    
    for(int i = i; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        Func<string, bool> selector1 = str => str.ToUpper() == data[i]  || str => str.ToLower() == data[i] ;
        
        // something like this func || func1 || func2 || func3... and so on
        selector = selector || selector1;
    }
    
    return selector;
}
```

Comment: By `||` do you mean you want to include both functions, or do you mean you want to include one function *or* the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dynamically create an Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate from Expression<Func<MyClass, string>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094489/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate-from-ex)

Comment: Do you need just execute such functions to first result true, or you need to combine Expressions for Linq query?

Comment: perhaps replace `selector || selector 1` with `s => selector(s) || selector1(s)`.

Comment: @Anubnit Please provide a full example where you might need `GetData`. Is it Entity Framework?

Comment: @JacobLockard My actual func is type of query. So all the func are multiple queries. So I want a combine func which contains all the queries as  ||.

Comment: @RoyCohen I have to append the func in a loop.

Comment: @LeszekMazur I need combine expression. As there are multiple functions like this function and all return Func<T,Tresult>. I have to combine all this func expression using AND operator(&&) for further use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need multiple `Func`s. Just use LINQ's `Any` function

```cs
public static Func<string, bool> GetData(string request)
{
    var data = request.Split(',');
    Func<string, bool> selector = str =>
        data.Any(d => d.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    
    return selector;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `Contains`

```cs
    Func<string, bool> selector = str =>
        data.Contains(str, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

> Note: `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is more efficient than calling `ToUpper` each time

Comment: `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is more secure than `ToUpper` (fe. ß and ss comparition), but may be author want to omit results with small letters in request

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope I am clear now

Answer (score 0):

This problem you can solve easier:

```cs
public static Func<string, bool> GetData(string request)
{
  return str => request.Split(',').contains(str.ToUpper());
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you *do* need to use a list of `Func`s, you can still combine them using LINQ

```cs
public static Func<string, bool> GetData(string request)
{
    var data = request.Split(',');
    var selectors = data.Select(d =>
        new Func<string, bool>(str => str.ToUpper() == d || str.ToLower() == d))  // would never use such code, but just your example
        .ToList();  // this is your list of selectors
    
    return str => selectors.Any(sel => sel(str));
}
```